# Project a 2D point on a 2D line

Tags: c#, math

I am struggling to get my function to work correctly. I am trying to project my 2D point onto a 2D line but it seems slightly off in its calculation but i am not sure why.

This is my code:

```
    //project a point on an infinite line defined by lineP1 and lineP2
    public static v2 Project(in v2 point, in v2 lineP1, in v2 lineP2)
    {
        var dir = (lineP2 - lineP1).normalize();
        var v = point - lineP1;
        var d = v.dot(dir);
        return lineP1 + dir * d;
    }
```

This is the result of my code:

[image]

As you can see it's not quite right, it seems slightly offset. What is the correct solution to this?

This image below shows where the point should be projected to:

[image]

Comment: It looks correct to me.  The red dot and pink dot are moving up/down by the same amount

Comment: @jdweng Yes but the projected point should surely be horizontally aligned with the red dot not slightly ahead of it? It should be right angled if you were to draw a second line from pink to red.

Comment: The horizontal location should be the same as the red dot.  You have the pink dot along the line between the two yellow points.

Comment: @jdweng yes it should be the same but its not hence the question. The pink dot should be aligned to the red dot. That would be a correct projection along the line.

Comment: Create a new point to return.  The new point has an x the same as the red dot.  The y position is the current y value.

Comment: Hi WDUK, I'm wondering if it's the camera projection that's making it look slightly out? Are you able to just print out the point values and do a manual check?

Comment: I agree this is most likely projection of the 3D camera issue and the projection of point is correct.

Comment: I second what others have said this looks like a camera projection issue. A potential solution si to do your projection in 3D directly rather than 2D.

Comment: Agree that math is correct.

Comment: Ah after a lot of digging around my code it turns out my dot product function was slightly incorrect. So yeah this was unsolvable from the info i provided and so the math is correct (when the dot product was actually working).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var dir = (lineP2 - lineP1).normalize();
var v = point - lineP1;
var d1 = v.dot(dir);
var d2 = dir.dot(dir);
return lineP1 + dir * (d1/d2);
```